# $K_1(A)$ is countable when A is separable C*-algebra

Tags: c-star-algebras, k-theory, topological-k-theory

We know that when A is a separable C*-algebra then $K_0(A)$ is countable.

How can I show that $K_1(A)$ is also countable?

Comment: One "cheap" way to see this is if you know Bott periodicity: $SA$ is still separable if $A$ is, and so $K_0(SA) = K_1(A)$ is countable.

Comment: Nailed it! That's an amazing answer

Comment: @PStheman The isomorphism $K_0(SA)=K_1(A)$ doesn't require Bott periodicity.  The isomorphism $K_1(SA)=K_0(A)$ does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an idea for how one can show that $K_1(A)$ is countable without taking suspensions:  Since the unitization of a separable $C^*$-algebra is separable, we may assume without loss of generality that $A$ is unital.  If $u,v$ are unitaries in $A$ and $\|u-v\|<2$, then $u$ is homotopic to $v$ in $\mathcal U(A)$ (the unitary group of $A$).  Since $A$ is separable, there is a countable set $\{u_n\}$ of unitaries in $A$ such that $\mathcal U(A)\subset \cup_nB(u_n,2)$  (the ball of radius $2$ centered at $u_n$). Thus there are countably many homotopy classes of unitaries in $A$.  The same applies to $M_n(A)$, and in the limit, we see that $K_1(A)$ is countable.

Comment: perfect!!. A question: Is there any examples of C*algebras suck that $K_1$ is uncountable??

Comment: I'm working on an answer to your next question, for which we get that $K_0(\ell^\infty)$ is uncountable.  Thus $K_1$ of the suspension  of $\ell^\infty$ is uncountable.

Comment: Excuse me but why $K_0(l^{\infty})$ is uncountable?

Comment: See the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3753134/ideas-for-calculating-k-0l-infty-and-k-1l-infty/3753186#3753186)

Comment: Again, thank you very much. That helped a lot.

Comment: No problem.  Glad to help!